# Trigger for AWS creation of resources (tagging on resource creation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, tags, billing

I want to tag AWS resources like dynamodb tables or EC2 objects right at the time of creation.
I will be using id or name fields of the objects to tag the resources.

Is there any 'post-create' trigger available?

--
The current problem is that even if I run my script to tag AWS resources, I can't run it immediately after every resource creation, I end up seeing a lot of billing untagged.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through AWS Service Catalog service. this has a capability of auto tagging of provisioned resources. [AWS reference link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/aws-service-catalog-announces-autotags-for-automatic-tagging-of-provisioned-resources/). AutoTags are tags that identify the portfolio, product, and user that launched a product, and are automatically applied by AWS Service Catalog to provisioned resources

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a lambda function to write a tag based on the CloudTrail event that is generated whenever a resource is created.

To get Lambda to run against a CloudTrail event you need to setup your CloudTrail to write events to a S3 bucket, then trigger the Lambda on the object creation event in the bucket.

The lambda uses the bucket key in its context object to read the event and determine if a tag needs to be applied.

Check the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail.html) for further detail about triggering Lambda from CloudTrail.

Also GorillaStack has [published an example on Github](https://github.com/GorillaStack/auto-tag) of using lambda to auto-tag newly created resources. You could use this as a basis for your solution.